# critical point, increasing/decreasing function and local extremum

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If $f ' (x) =(x-1)^2 (x+2)$ is given and we're asked to find the 3 things in the title:

for critical points we put $f ' (x)=0$ and the values of x we get are critical points

for increasing/decreasing functions we will divide intervals according to critical point and take a test point to see sign of x and thus conclude if it's increasing or decreasing

for local extremums we can use second derivative test?

Are these three approaches correct or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Note that critical point can be at a place where the derivative does not exist. Also the extrema can be at the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right!

The **first derivative test** uses the derivatives of a function to locate the **critical points** of a function. To calculate the critical points we need to solve the equation $f^{'}(x)=0$. The computed values of the parameter $x$ will be critical.

The **second-derivative test** uses the value of the **second derivative** at those points to determine whether such points are a **local maximum** or a **local minimum**. If the function f is twice-differentiable at a critical point x (i.e. a point where $f^{'}(x)=0$), then:

1. If $f^{''}(x)<0$, then f has a local maximum at x.
2. If $f^{''}(x)>0$, then f has a local minimum at x.
3. If $f^{''}(x)=0$, the test is inconclusive.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Some corrections, for technical correctness:

> for critical points we put $f ' (x)=0$

1. Critical points are where $f'(x)$

   - either **doesn't exist** $(y=|x|$ at $0)$
   - or equals $0.$

> for local extremums we can use second derivative test

2. For local extrema that *are* stationary turning points, the sign test is one alternative (among others) to the second-derivative test.
3. But a local extremum might **also** be

   - a non-stationary turning point $(y=|x|$ at $0),$ or
   - a stationary non-turning point $(y=3$ at $0),$ or
   - neither stationary nor turning $(y=\sqrt x$ at $0)$ !

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to divide the interval according to whether $f$ is increasing/decreasing anyway, then you don't need the second derivative test. Just look at the monotonicity of $f$ near its critical points to decide local extremums.

In your example, $x=-2$ is a critical point of $f$. Note that $f'(x) < 0$ for $x < -2$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $-2 < x < 1$. This means $f$ is strictly decreasing on the left of $x=-2$ and strictly increasing on the right of $x=-2$. Thus, $x=-2$ is a strict local minimum of $f$.

You can do a similar analysis for another critical point $x=1$.